# How do I accurately center text horizontally next to a float

Tags: html, css, css-float, center

I have a container that has some text floated right, and other text that I want horizontally centered relative to the entire container. The code below only centers the text relative to the space left of the floated text. The container's width may vary depending on screen size, and both the centered and right text are dynamic and can contain more or less characters.

```css
#holder {
    margin:15px;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
#right_text {
    float:right;
}
#center_text {
    text-align:center;
}
<div id="holder">
    <div id="right_text">back to page 3</div>
    <div id="center_text">load results 10-30 of 312</div>
</div>
```

I don't want to absolute position the right text because the centered text may overlap it. The centered text should instead wordwrap before hitting the right text and also still center horizontally.

I don't want to just add left/right padding to the centered text container because the right text is dynamic and I don't know the amount of padding needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/eJFw6/8/

Comment: The only way to make `#center_text` to ignore the float is to position the floated element absolutely instead of floating it, and then adding a left AND right padding to `#center_text`.

Since you mentioned that the right text is dynamic, why not set the left and right padding of `#center_text` using JS?

Comment: Yes, i COULD use JS to assign the padding based on the width of the right text, but that would be a pain. I'm looking for a CSS solution if possible.

Comment: I doubt that is possible. And the JS solution isn't a pain. I can imagine using 5 or less lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#center_text {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: floating the center text left collapses the container which makes text-align:center useless. I would need to assign a width in order for it to work, and i don't know the width because the right text is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

So, a javascript solution was recommended and I came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#center_text").css('padding','0px '+$("#right_text").outerWidth()+'px');
});
```

I also added some left and bottom padding to the right text so if the container is skinnier the center text wraps nicely.

```css
#holder {
    margin:15px auto;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:280px
}
#right_text {
    float:right;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
#center_text {
    text-align:center;
}
<div id="holder">
    <div id="right_text">back to page 3</div>
    <div id="center_text">load results 10-30 of 312</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/littleRoom/eJFw6/12/